# iOS10 Messages Link Preview Image

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, ios10, twitter-card

Any iOS10 beta testers out there know if Messages uses a syntax similar to Facebook Open Graph to set things like meta descriptions and images?

I'm building a site and would like to have it ready for when iOS10 is launched.

Here's the type of stuff I'm talking about:

```
<!-- Facebook Meta -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Site | Title of Page" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/im-content/social-post-images/facebook image.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com" />
<meta property="og:site-name" content="Site | Title of Page"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Here is a description of my site that will show up in the Facebook card." />
```

And here's the image/info I'm trying to control:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's at least using [Open Graph](http://ogp.me) and [Twitter Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/).

### Demos

**[Open Graph](https://www.j-26.com/test/facebook.html)**

*Markup:*

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/facebook.jpg"/>
```

*Preview:*

[image]

---

**[Twitter Card](https://www.j-26.com/test/twitter.html)**

*Markup:*

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/twitter.jpg"/>
```

[image]

---

### Notable findings

I tested [this page](https://www.j-26.com/test/) using Twitter Card and Open graph and iOS seemed to prefer Open Graph. On the test page, the Twitter Card markup is placed before the Open Graph markup *and* the image used for Twitter Card is **smaller** than the one used in Open Graph. Despite the smaller size and earlier placement, iOS chose to display the image from Open Graph.

Comment: Thanks so much, John! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Have you managed to get this working over SSL? My http og:image tags work great with raw http, but any https images do not load, even if I use og:image:secure_url

Comment: Your answer has a typo - the twitter card markup should say `twitter:image` instead of `og:image` -- confused me for min.

Comment: Good catch. Fixing it now.